# Make synchronous orchestrate.io queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronization, orchestrate

I just started using orchestrate.io as my database and am using the [NodeJS client](https://orchestrate.io/docs/clients/nodejs).

My program is a very simple one but does not behave as desired which is due to the query running asynchronously.

Code:

```
var db = require('orchestrate')("xxxxxx");
db.get('bar', 'foo')
.then(function (res) {
  console.log("I got a response!");
})
.fail(function (err) {
  console.log("I failed to get a response");
});
console.log("I should have data by now..");
```

Output:

```
I should have data by now..
I got a response!
```

What I would like to have:

```
I got a response!
I should have data by now..
```

This is just some code I wrote to illustrate the issue and my actual code is far more complex and the query is within a login function that ends up returning `false` (per the end of the function) before finishing the query which would return `true` instead which very much breaks my login system. The only solution would be to somehow make the query synchronous but I can't see anything touching that in the docs (Please point me to them if I missed it).

Note: I am *very* new to nodejs and javascript in general.

Note 2: Callbacks would not really work for the code I actually have so no need to even try that.

Comment: Down vote justification?

Comment: "Callbacks would not really work for the code I actually have so no need to even try that." Uhhh, that's the **only** thing to try. You can't make an async function magically synchronous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js is designed such that all I/O is done in an asynchronous manner. If you have written code that expects database calls to be executed synchronously, you will need to refactor to make it fit Node.js's non-blocking model.

Comment: Thanks for finding my SO question ;)